# Setting routersnapshot on click - Angular

Tags: angular

I currently have my auth-guard setup for when a user puts a site url of a listing in the address bar, it takes them to the login page when unauthenthenticated. Once authenticated, it redirects to original URL like it should. This part works fine.

I have another scenario where I'm trying to store the router snapshot when a user clicks a login button  to buy the product they are currently seeing in a read-only page so that after they login, it redirects them to the same product page to purchase, but I'm confused on how to get the button click logic to work so that it'll just work with my current AuthGuard setup.  I haven't been able to find a good example. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how it works. I appreciate any help!

auth-guard.ts

```
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router
} from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    this.authService.redirectUrl = state.url;
    const isAuth = this.authService.getIsAuth();
    if (!isAuth) {
      console.log("Logging out in AuthGuard");
      this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
    }
    return isAuth;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would use localStorage or sessionStorage. There might happen other things between product page and login success, so more things for you to care about. So for ex. check in guard if there is selected product and redirect to its page, if so

Comment: Great suggestion. I went ahead and it did that and it's working great. Thanks

Comment: Great. Just to add - for extensive usage, cookies might deliver more value